# PHP 5.6.x lost ability to connect to ODBC source

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I have a strange problem. My server has been running PHP 5.6 for years no problem. (WinServer Std 2K8 SP2, IIS 6, MySQL 5.6 {separate server}, PHP 5.6)

We connect it to a DB2 server at our parent company. Today (2017-02-14) the ODBC connection (PDO_ODBC) started returning "could not find driver".

Excel is able to use the same ODBC connection to query the database - the ODBC connection is working.

I tried using both the PDO method and procedural method to connect. Failures in seeing the driver both ways.

From `phpinfo()`:
[ODBC Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIusy.png)
[PDO Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cf4b.png)

Code snippet:

```
$dsn = "odbc:workingODBCdsn";
$user = "xxxx";
$password = "yyyy";
$conn = null;
$results = array();

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

if ($conn) {
    $qry = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($qry) {
        $qry->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        foreach ($qry as $row) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }
    }
}

print "<pre>" . print_r($results, true) . "</pre>";

//ALT Method
$conn = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $password);
$results = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

print "<pre>" . print_r($results, true) . "</pre>";
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Based on other questions, looked in the registry and made sure the ODBC Admin is looking for a file that exists. (IBM DB2 ODBC driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server's PHP instance switched from IIS to IISExpress. Switching it back to (full) IIS, and enduring all appropriate PDO drivers were enabled fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the unixODBC or ibm_db2 (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php)? It it recommended to use IBM DB2 Universal Database with “ibm_db2” extension. It’s faster and more efficient than using generic driver.  It calls the native IBM DB2 functions with the extension.

Check out the db2_* functions from [php.net IBM DB2 functions manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ibm-db2.php)

Comment: Because of corporate policies, we can't access directly